# creating a new stream for another call

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-node, twilio-conference

I am using twilio's connect().stream() for bidirectional synchronous stream.
Now at a certain point i want to call another number for that i need a new stream so that conversations wont get mixed.
But as that is indirectly getting executed inside media event(socket) , new stream is not getting generated.

I did research and its telling me to use .
But to add participant , its asking for conferenceSid.
But i dont know how can i get the conferenceSid.

i just cant get where i am going wrong?

const conference = twiml.dial().conference('MyConference', {
startConferenceOnEnter: true,
endConferenceOnExit: true,
});
console.log('conference: ', conference, "conference SID::", conference?.sid);
this.client.conferences.list({ friendlyName: 'MyConference', limit: 20 })
.then(conferences => conferences.forEach(c => console.log(c.sid)));

did this for getting conferenceSid , but got nothing